# What is the different between chrome web app and web app?

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome

I check out the google web app, it seems that this is only a page for hosting web page/ application... What make it so different? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that google chrome web browser allows you install Extensions e.g. apps or utilities. Safari 5 allows extensions however, these are usually like tool bars or website enhancers.

EDIT: I also forgot to add, this is kind of like the App store apple has. Google will use this for there upcoming O/S: Chrome OS. Because Chrome OS is web based, many of it's apps will involve it being written in html and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A google chrome web app = normal web app + access/use of Google Chrome extension API.